# lua: local functioncall with local string -> nil

Tags: lua, local, null, string.format

I got this code, in which "call_name" seems to stay nil.

```
function mdbTest(conf)
  if conf.m_string:sub(6,9) == "MBUS" then
      local print_name, call_name = "MBUS","mbus"
  else
      local print_name, call_name = "MDB","mdb"
  end

  local port_handler = rawio.open(string.format("/dev/%s",call_name))
end
```

In the end, this isn't a real problem due to the fact that I just can make call_name public, but I would like to know why it is like that. Can someone explain it please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`call_name` is in both cases local to the `if/else` block, i.e.:

```
function test()
    if true then
        local a = 42
    end
    print(a)
end

test()
```

→ `nil`

fix: declare it in the scope of its usage

```
function test()
    local a
    if true then
        a = 42
    end
    print(a)
end

test()
```

→ `42`